# Scipy Optimize (L-BFGS-B) Output : What does variable M represent?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, scipy-optimize

> RUNNING THE L-BFGS-B CODE

> Machine precision = 2.220D-16

> N =          425     M =           10

> At X0         0 variables are exactly at the bounds

What is the meaning of variable M? I know N stands for the number of trainable parameters.

Comment: It seems to be the *the maximum number of variable metric corrections used to define the limited memory matrix* see [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/cdcbb40062aa4fe2e324e590f159dd1f51ea6375/scipy/optimize/lbfgsb_src/lbfgsb.f#L67) and [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/cdcbb40062aa4fe2e324e590f159dd1f51ea6375/scipy/optimize/lbfgsb_src/lbfgsb.f#L2698)